# Post data using javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Trying to post data using javascript (when the page load)
The coordinates are generated but nothing else hapens, What am I doing wrong... 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
<p id="demo">Cords are displayed here...</p>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo"); //this display the cords only to ensure script works

function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}
function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude +" "+ position.coords.longitude; //this test if the cords are generated
lg=position.coords.latitude +" "+ position.coords.longitude;

var url = "navigator.asp"; // this page is linked to a database which saves the post
var params = "id=1&lg="+lg;
xhr.open("POST", url+"?"+params, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(params);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to send the parameters in both the URL and `xhr.send()`. Use one or the other, depending on what the server script expects. But I don't think sending them both should cause a problem.

Comment: Barmar, your comment helped me to realize that my javascript skill  was very rusty. I did a little refresher and re-wrote the code. You are right I don't need to send url in xhr.send() --plus-- I placed the "post" part of the code in a function which is triggered by function "shoPosition". I also passed the geo-location from shoPosition to new postFunction in a variable. It now works great.